# Delete a specific field from a database

Tags: sql

How can I delete the value of a field from a database, using query code? I only know where the field is located in the database. (ex: column['phone number']row[3])

It should be something like this `"DELETE FROM ...  WHERE ..."`

Comment: Do you ask for a code how to delete from database, or simply what SQl Query is needed?

Comment: Setting a field to a null value is not the same thing that deleting the whole row. ([See UPDATE/DELETE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp))

Comment: Have you tried googling "sql delete" ?

Comment: I think you are asking to delete value of field that you are unknown with its name , but you are aware with its index position, right ?

Comment: Does the row have an id associated with it or some other unique identifier?

Comment: You don't want to delete based on row numbers.  Delete records based on what the value of the field (or some other field) is.

Comment: Are you wanting to set the value of a column to null or are you wanting to remove the entire record?  These are rather different things that I wonder if you understand Relational Databases as this is a fairly basic question on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like delete the field in database i.e. if you want to remove the complete row then you can do that easily like this

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1=@myValue
```

But if you wanted to remove one value of the row in that case you should update that value as `NULL`

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN1=NULL WHERE COLUMN1=@myValue
```

I have used where clause from my imagination. you can always use whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The DELETE statement allows you to delete RECORDS.
When you want to set a field to an empty value, use the UPDATE statement.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp) for more info.

Comment: OK! I use UPDATE statement! But, how can I update a field when I don't know what value it has?

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE [YOUR_TABLE] SET [YOUR_FIELD] = NULL WHERE [YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY] = VALUE`

Answer (score -1):

Yes first you need to use delete command. Then after this insert update command then only the records will be deleted from the database. I agree that you have deleted records but its not showing because you haven't updated it.

Comment: He does *not* need to use the `DELETE` command. Delete will clear the whole row, it looks like he wants to clear a specific field. In which case `UPDATE` would be used.